# Running separate code while a socket server is running?

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, udp

How can I have a socket server running that accepts incoming connections and deals with that part of the code, while not having code waiting for new connections stuck in that same loop?

I am just starting trying to learn. Would a TCP Handler be useful?

I just need some simple examples on this topic. I'm wanting something like having a commands portion in the server. So i can do certain things while the server is running.

EDIT: What I'm trying to do:

```
1 - TCP server for multiple clients
2 - Respond to more than one at a time when needed
3 - Text input availability at all time, to be used for getting/setting info
4 - A simple way to get/save client address info. Currently using a list to save them.
```

Comment: "Haha."?  What?  How about you start out with "reword it better" rather than waiting for us to ask.  Paragraphs help.  Steps and sequences help.  Sometimes code samples help.  "Haha." doesn't help.

Comment: Sorry, i just don't know how to exactly word it. And i don't have any examples cause i don't know where to start. Im just not sure how to have the server in the loop for listening to connections. But still able to have the server looking for any input that i may want to put into the cmd window, and act to it accordingly.

Comment: (1) Capitalize "I", please.  (2) Remove the "Haha.".  (3) Write down -- step-by-step -- what you think your server is supposed to do.  Use separate paragraphs.  Number the steps.  Do something to explain what you think is supposed to happen.  We can't guess.  (4) Spell check.  "Separate", for example.

Comment: Updated it, hopes it helps to clarify things.

Comment: Tried to clean it up some for you. Please learn how to properly use your shift key and add paragraph breaks, and remember you're not texting or chatting with your friends here. "Haha" and "i'm" and "lol" and unnecessary "so i'm just wanting gonna maybe cani" poor grammar and phrasing and quotes just make things harder to read, and therefore harder for people to help you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python has builtin support of asynchronous socket handling in `asyncore` module (http://docs.python.org/library/asyncore.html).

Asynchronous socket handling means that You have to execute at least one iteration of socket processing loop inside Your code (main loop):

```
asyncore.loop(count=1)
```

Example taken from documentation:

```
import asyncore
import socket

class EchoHandler(asyncore.dispatcher_with_send):

    def handle_read(self):
        data = self.recv(8192)
        if data:
            self.send(data)

class EchoServer(asyncore.dispatcher):

    def __init__(self, host, port):
        asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self)
        self.create_socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.set_reuse_addr()
        self.bind((host, port))
        self.listen(5)

    def handle_accept(self):
        pair = self.accept()
        if pair is None:
            pass
        else:
            sock, addr = pair
            print('Incoming connection from %s' % repr(addr))
            handler = EchoHandler(sock)

server = EchoServer('localhost', 8080)
# Note that here loop is infinite (count is not given)
asyncore.loop()
```

Each time the socket accepts the connection `handle_accept` is called by the loop. Each time the data is available to read from socket `handle_read` is called and so on.

You can use both TCP and UDP sockets in this manner.

Comment: Would this be a better setup for a gaming environment compared to a normal socket TCP server?

Comment: What do You mean by normal TCP server? Btw. asynchronous socket handling has a huge advantage of not involving any threading into processing.

Answer (score 2):

You can run your socket server in a [thread](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html).

```
import threading
import SocketServer

server = SocketServer.TCPServer(('localhost', 0), SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler)
th = threading.Thread(target=server.serve_forever)
th.daemon = True
th.start()
```

Comment: So, if i have a threading server. For like a online game, i could have one thread for the players to connect to. And another thread for command inputs? I just read that using threads per connection is bad. So using 1 thread for all of the clients would work?

Comment: In the example above only the the `sever.serve_forever` loop that will be run in a thread so that your script can continue executing while in the background there is a server listening to new connections. you can check also the doc: http://docs.python.org/library/socketserver.html to know how to creating a threading server (fork a new thread for each request) or a forking server (for a new process for each request) ... , or maybe even better take a look at twisted (http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) it can help you create a no-blocking server, Hope i answer your question :)

Comment: I assume each thread can have its own loop then, right? If so, that is exactly what i'm looking for. Seems like threading is kind of like running multiple scripts in one.

Comment: Threading is parallel processing so that one process in your code doesn't block another. If you're doing this for a game you'd be better off using a package/module that handles TCP connections. Which I'm sure is possible with twisted since it's supposed to be used for networking/internet applications. But I haven't used twisted myself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are asking, but normally on the server side, you make socket(), bind() and listen() calls to setup the socket, and then loop around an accept() call. This accept() call blocks until a client connection is made.

For simple servers, you handle whatever request the client makes within the loop. For real-world servers, you need to spawn some other mechanism (e.g. a new thread or process, depending on the language/platform) to handle the request asynchronously, so that the original loop can iterate again on the accept() call and go back to listening for connections.

See the Python socket doc for more info and examples in Python:

http://docs.python.org/howto/sockets.html