# How can I run other code while I am listening on a socket in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to socket programming and have created a simple multi-connection client server program from the following resource: https://realpython.com/python-sockets/

The issue I have can be found in this code:

```
import selectors
sel = selectors.DefaultSelector()

# ...

while True:
    events = sel.select(timeout=None)
    print("This is a test!")
    for key, mask in events:
        if key.data is None:
            accept_wrapper(key.fileobj)
        else:
            service_connection(key, mask)
```

My goal is to run some code after the

```
events = sel.select(timeout=None)
```

line regardless even if an event is not generated. The issue is that as soon as this line of code hits, none of the code after will be ran as it is waiting for an event. How can I get the print() statement to be executed when there are no events?

While searching for answers to this, I did come across this thread:
[Python Socket Programming - need to do something while listening for connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9306412/python-socket-programming-need-to-do-something-while-listening-for-connections)

However, this seems a bit more than what I want to do (I don't need to send/receive anything). Not to mention, I didn't see anything that specifically addressed my issue (though to be fair, I might not have understood it). I also saw another thread ([Running separate code while a socket server is running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421339/running-separate-code-while-a-socket-server-is-running)) that talked about asyncore, but again...not quite sure how I could use this in my current program.

Anyone have any advice on how I can get that print() statement to execute while waiting for events?

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass a timeout value in seconds as a parameter to the selector function.

For example:

```
events = sel.select(timeout=10)
```

This way after 10 seconds it will execute the next block of code after events.

[https://docs.python.org/3/library/selectors.html#module-selectors](https://docs.python.org/3/library/selectors.html#module-selectors://)

Refer to the documentation for a deeper explanation.

(I know the question is 3 years old but this might help someone)